# Creating a generic Numeric class in C++

Tags: c++

What is the best approach to create a generic Numeric class in C++ ? I'm thinking at an object that can contain integers, floats and doubles.

My first idea is to use a union that will be used in a Numeric class where you can define the allowed operations for each type. Something like:

```
union mixed_number{
    int a;
    float b;
    double c;
};

class Number{
    //define operations
    ...
};
```

Please let me know if there is a better approach.

Comment: Candidate for a better approach: just use `double`. What would be the advantage of the hypothetical `Numeric` class over this?

Comment: Oh, when you said generic I thought you meant generics... Anyway, why? Do you want to write a javascript interpreter or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I want to write a small interpreter and in the same time I'm trying to understand how dynamic languages like Python and Ruby define their data. I know I can look in the source code, but I want to try a few ideas first.

Answer (score 6):

I made a generic Numeric class a while ago. Here:

```
template< typename T> class TypeWrapper
{
    T value;
public:
    TypeWrapper(T v): value(v) {}

    operator T() { return value; }

    // basic arithmetic operators
    void operator = (T v){  value = v; }

    TypeWrapper operator + (T v) { return TypeWrapper( value + v ); }
    TypeWrapper operator - (T v) { return TypeWrapper( value - v); }
    TypeWrapper operator * (T v) { return TypeWrapper( value * v); }
    TypeWrapper operator / (T v) { return TypeWrapper( value / v); }
    TypeWrapper operator % (T v) { return TypeWrapper( value % v); }

    void operator += (T v) { value += v; }
    void operator -= (T v) { value -= v; }
    void operator *= (T v) { value *= v; }
    void operator /= (T v) { value /= v; }
    void operator %= (T v) { value %= v; }

    T operator ++ () { return ++value; }
    T operator -- () { return --value;}
    T operator ++ (int v) { return value++; }
    T operator -- (int v) { return value--; }

    // conditions
    bool operator == (T v) { return value == v; }
    bool operator != (T v) { return value != v; }
    bool operator > (T v) { return value > v; }
    bool operator < (T v) { return value < v; }
    bool operator >= (T v) { return value >= v; }
    bool operator <= (T v) { return value <= v; }

    T toPrimitive() { return value; }
    string toString()
    {
        stringstream ss;
        string rtn;

        ss << value;
        ss >> rtn;

        return rtn;
    }
};

// just to make things easier for a future move.
#define NumericTypeWrapper TypeWrapper

    typedef NumericTypeWrapper< int > Integer;
    typedef NumericTypeWrapper< double > Double;
    typedef NumericTypeWrapper< float > Float;
}
```

Comment: it is absolutely incorrect class! for example bool operator == (T v) { return value == v; } doesn't "work" for double.

Comment: I don't think the OP meant templates with "generic".

Comment: @MrLister oh damn. Then what does he mean? Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker The OP wants to write a small interpreter and in the same time try to understand how dynamic languages like Python and Ruby define their data. He knows he can look in the source code, but he wants to try a few ideas first.

Comment: @mmisu Oops, your profile doesn't mention your gender. Sorry for any misconception.